# Sending JSON from Python to Node via child_process gets truncated if too long, how to fix?

Tags: python, node.js, stdout, child-process

My Node & Python backend is running just fine, but I now encountered an issue where if a JSON I'm sending from Python back no Node is too long, it gets split into two and my JSON.parse at the Node side fails.

How should I fix this? For example, the first batch clips at

```
... [1137.6962355826706, -100.78015825640887], [773.3834338399517, -198
```

and the second one has the remaining few entries

```
.201506231888], [-87276.575065248, -60597.8827676457], [793.1850250453127, 
-192.1674702207991], [1139.4465453979683, -100.56741252031816], 
[780.498416769341, -196.04064849430705]]}
```

Do I have to create some logic on the Node side for long JSONs or is this some sort of a buffering issue I'm having on my Python side that I can overcome with proper settings? Here's all I'm doing on the python side:

```
outPoints, _ = cv2.projectPoints(inPoints, np.asarray(rvec), 
np.asarray(tvec), np.asarray(camera_matrix), np.asarray(dist_coeffs))

# flatten the output to get rid of double brackets per result before JSONifying
flattened = [val for sublist in outPoints for val in sublist]
print(json.dumps({'testdata':np.asarray(flattened).tolist()}))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

And on the Node side:

```
// Handle python data from print() function
  pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data){

    try {
      // If JSON handle the data
      console.log(JSON.parse(data.toString()));
    } catch (e) {
      // Otherwise treat as a log entry
      console.log(data.toString());
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emitted data is chunked, so if you want to parse a `JSON` you will need to join all the chunks, and on `end` perform `JSON.parse`.

> By default, pipes for stdin, stdout, and stderr are established
>   between the parent Node.js process and the spawned child. These pipes
>   have limited (and platform-specific) capacity. If the child process
>   writes to stdout in excess of that limit without the output being
>   captured, the child process will block waiting for the pipe buffer to
>   accept more data.

In [linux](https://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe) each chunk is limited to `65536` bytes.

> In Linux versions before 2.6.11, the capacity of a pipe was the same
>   as the system page size (e.g., 4096 bytes on i386). Since Linux
>   2.6.11, the pipe capacity is 65536 bytes.

```
let result = '';
pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', data => {
    result += data.toString();
    // Or Buffer.concat if you prefer.
});

pythonProcess.stdout.on('end', () => {
    try {
      // If JSON handle the data
      console.log(JSON.parse(result));
    } catch (e) {
      // Otherwise treat as a log entry
      console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Clear and concise answer

Comment: How should I go about sending log info to Node? Now that I'm combining the buffers, I can't use print() to send any log messages as those will now be concatenated along with any JSON data I send.

Is there a way to trigger stdout.on('end') manually to clear the buffer?